# Can someone explain me what are X, I and Pr in this proof ? and also why first sigma start from j=i+1?

Tags: algorithm, math, linked-list, hashtable, clrs

I am reading **CLRS Algorithm** and i saw this Theorem. 

**Theorem 11.2**: In a hash table in which collisions are resolved by chaining, a successful search
takes **average-case time: theta(1+n/m)** under the assumption of simple uniform hashing. 
in this theorem, **m => number of slots in table** and **n => number of elements in each slot** . 
 
and this is the proof: 
[image]

Help Me Please. I can not understand this yellow parts at all :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I` is the [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Its value is `1` when the condition is met, and `0` otherwise.

`X_ij` is the indicator of hash collision. That is, `X_ij == 1` when `h(k_i) == h(k_j)`, and `X_ij == 0` when `h(k_i) != h(k_j)`.

`Pr` is probability. The highlighted statement means that the probability of a hash collision is `1/m`.

The sum starts from `i+1` because in order to find `x_i`, we only need to examine elements inserted after `x_i`. Those inserted *before* `x_i` will be located *after* it in the list, so the search will terminate before reaching them.